# i have code like this need to use for loop for the existing code

Tags: angularjs

i have code like this need to use for loop for the existing code instead of showing 1,2,3 etc code is inside the javascript file i have tried with with different types but am getting any data

```
$rootScope.AgeM = [
    {M: '1'},
    {M: '2'},
    {M: '3'},
    {M: '4'},
    {M: '5'},
    {M: '6'},
    {M: '7'},
    {M: '8'},
    {M: '9'},
    {M: '10'},
    {M: '11'},
    {M: '12'},
]
```

the for is in array .repeating same data or entering number from 1 to 12 feeling bit difficulty

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Object.keys

```
  function getAge() {
    let AgeM = [
        {M: '1'},
        {M: '2'},
        {M: '3'},
        {M: '4'},
        {M: '5'},
        {M: '6'},
        {M: '7'},
        {M: '8'},
        {M: '9'},
        {M: '10'},
        {M: '11'},
        {M: '12'},
    ]
    let age;
    let index = 0;

    Object.keys(AgeM).forEach(function (key) {

        age = AgeM[key];
        console.log('for index ', index + ' age is :' + age.M);
        index++;
    });
}
```